# Fetching Data from Bloomberg in VBA

Tags: vba, bloomberg

I am working on a VBA project that fetches financial data from Bloomberg and calculates returns.
At the moment data for 2020 to 2022 is available. 
How can I put a dynamic check in the code that checks data for 2023 is available and if it is then updates the calculation using data from 2021 to 2023? Thank you!!

Following is the code I am using right now:

```
    Function getTotalGrowth(k As Integer)
    Dim bbg As New BBG_Function

    Dim gdpGrowth As Variant

    ReDim indexData(5, 2)
    indexData(1, 1) = "ECGDEU 20 Index"
    indexData(2, 1) = "ECGDEU 21 Index"
    indexData(3, 1) = "ECGDEU 22 Index"
    indexData(4, 1) = "XYZ Curncy"
    indexData(5, 1) = "ABC Index"

    indexData(1, 2) = "ECGDUS 20 Index"
    indexData(2, 2) = "ECGDUS 21 Index"
    indexData(3, 2) = "ECGDUS 22 Index"
    indexData(4, 2) = "XYZ Curncy"
    indexData(5, 2) = "ABC Index"

    gdpGrowth = ((1 + bbg.BDP(indexData(1, k), "PX_LAST") / 100) * (1 + bbg.BDP(indexData(2, k), 
                "PX_LAST") / 100) * (1 + bbg.BDP(indexData(3, k), "PX_LAST") / 100) ^ 3) ^ (1 / 5) - 1

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
Dim y as Long, yStart as Long
if bbg.BDP("ECGDEU 23 Index", "PX_LAST") = 0 then
   yStart=20
else
   yStart=21
end if
for y=yStart to yStart+2
   indexData(1, 1) = "ECGDEU " & y & " Index"
   indexData(2, 1) = "ECGDEU " & y & " Index"
   ...
next
```

Comment: Thanks Jörgen. It works. I revisited this project after a break.